# Controlling the precision of floating point number in matlab

Tags: matlab, precision, floating

I am dividing a number, say

```
x=2;
y=1/3;
z=x*y;
```

I expect z to be `0.66666666666667` i.e. 14 numbers after decimal point and the same for y. Now when I do that I get `0.6667` only. How to expand the answer into exact 14 digit precision?

Comment: Try typing `format long g` in the command line

Comment: it gives me 15 digits after decimal point.i want exactly 14.how to do that

Comment: Then round off to 14 places

Answer (score 7):

If it is just about diplaying the number you can use the `sprintf` function

```
str = sprintf('%.14f', pi); % print PI with exactly 14 digits after decimal point
disp(str);
```

Or `fprintf` with just one line:

```
fprintf('%.14f', pi);
```

[fprintf](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) is for writing to files but prints the string result to the screen if no file identifier is given.

Answer (score 6):

If you actually want the number to have that precision then round off to 14 places like this:

```
format long g

x=2;
y=1/3;
z=x*y;
round(z*1e14)/1e14

ans =      0.66666666666667
```

If it's just about displaying then use Deve's `sprintf` solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can type in matlab :

```
digits(10)
```

it gives you more floating point precision, or also

```
digits(20)
```

for example:

```
 a=1/3
ans = 0.3333
digits(10)
 vpa(a)
 ans= 0.3333333333
```

search help of matlab by typing doc  in command window and then search : digits

Comment: oops, i mean  digits(10)

Comment: Using the Variable Precision Arithmetic module is an ass-backwards (no offence) way of showing more digits of precision if you only require a small amount of digits to be shown.  Only use `vpa` if you require much larger amount of digits of precision.  In this particular case, `vpa` is not required here.