# MATLAB : function call returns different value for same x

Tags: matlab, function

[image: MATLAB debugging]

I am currently in the debugging process, and I found that this is happening, ruining everything. For reference, f =  @(x)a*x^3+b*x^2+c*x+d (where in this specific case, a = 2, b = -7, c = -8, d = 16).

Also, I notice that temp == -1.6861 returns false..

Comment: I'm guessing it is related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331068/controlling-the-precision-of-floating-point-number-in-matlab); i.e., `temp` has a lot more significant digits than five that are suppressed by Matlab's default display format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical floating-point problem. Your number is NOT -1.6861, but something close to it. Try `format long` and then looking at `temp`. Or even better, try `sprintf('%25.20f',temp)`. `temp` is the root of your function `f` as it should be, just not exactly -1.6861.

You actually have to be really careful with this:

```
(1/3-7/3/7)==0
```

is false, since

```
>> (1/3-7/3/7)

ans =

  -5.5511e-17
```